# Docker image build stuck on pending

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

I have been trying to do some fixes to my custom Docker [image](https://github.com/Jrachman/tensorflow-py3-docker) (basically TensorFlow for Python3 with tolerance for heavier computation load) and all of a sudden when I push to build on [Docker Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76QB2.png), it gets stuck on the "Pending" status. The longest I have waited for the build to get out of that state was over an hour but have not seen it move to the "Building" stage. I have checked [Docker System Status](https://status.docker.com) for any anomalies and nothing has been detected. Let me know what is going wrong with my git or in my Docker image on the cloud.

[image]
[image]
(note: whenever I click "Trigger," the status goes from "Building" back to "Failed" which makes no sense)

Comment: It can happen. Maybe you are out of memory, because Docker loads all the files in the build context into its memory. Restart the daemon, it should be ok.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add some folders to `.dockerignore` and the image is gigantic?

Comment: @Fabien how do I restart daemon?

Comment: service docker restart

Comment: @Grimmy I don't have a `.dockerignore` and the image is big but should not take this long to pend

Comment: @Fabien I just did it and it didn't do anything that I can see. I will add another screenshot.

Comment: @Fabien screenshot added.

Comment: When I build the image locally I get `HTTP error 404 while getting http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.0.0-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl` so the exit status of the build is definitely non-zero.

Comment: @Grimmy Oh well I want to use the version of tensorflow that is compatible with python3. Thought that changing `27` to `35` by `cp` would help. I assume then that `cp27` will be just fine?

Comment: @JulianRachman List all the objects by visiting https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow then search for "cpu".

Comment: @Grimmy ok I have searched.

Comment: @Grimmy I found tensorflow-0.10.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: and this which is higher tensorflow-1.2.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl (tbh I am kinda lost)

Comment: @Grimmy tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl <- this one is has the highest version number that I can find

Comment: That matches the docs : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#prerequisite_python_and_pip. Im pretty sure the same package works for py2 and 3

Comment: @Grimmy Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149277/discussion-between-julian-rachman-and-grimmy).

Comment: @Grimmy Still doesn't look like anything has changed.\

Comment: @JulianRachman see chat